# I'm getting corrupt data in Redis on ElastiCache on a LIST

Tags: redis

Multiple nodes are LPUSH-ing to the same key at the same time.
One node is reading everything from the list with LRANGE 0 -1, then clears the key with DEL.
I'm getting corrupted elements with Redis logs in the middle of the element contents:

```
{"Async":0,"Read":0,"Sync*3
$5
LPUSH
$8
cadvisor
$1467
{"timestamp":1525212335847331,"machine_name"
```

The curly braces are part of the JSON object that is an element of the LIST.

How does Redis, and in particular ElastiCache handle concurrent LPUSH's ?

Comment: Redis is single threaded, so concurrent `LPUSH` commands should be atomic. How are you using `LPUSH`?

Comment: It is pushed using `garyburd/redisgo` client here: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/804cd3c133b8bc29a84727a31f700b180b961520/storage/redis/redis.go#L106